# Unable to paste control on windows form C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, desktop-application

Problem is when i pick up user defined control from toolbox and paste it on #Home form its shows error.
I have attached the screenshots of user defined control (stock), windows form  (Home) and error Message below
[image: Stock Control[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7ayL.png)[[image: Error Screen]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdM14.png)

Comment: " user defined control from toolbox and paste it on #Home " you are trying to copy paste from toolbox. try drag and drop. Also where did you paste them. Within the Panel.?

Comment: You have some error in the uc. Probably in the OnPaint event, which only comes up when the designer tries to render it. Comment out portions to find the culprit!

Comment: @user3501749 i also tried to drag and drop but same message shows everytime, and yes i am pasting in panel

Comment: Note the error will not be a syntax error but usually accessing some property or resource that will only be available at runtime. Often one can workaround with an `if (DesignMode)` check..